# failed to install laravel via composer, failed to install symfony

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, composer-php

i just installed laravel for the first time and got this error, i have reinstalled Composer many times but it doesn't work, maybe you guys can help me out

- PHP version 8.2

[image: composer error]

[image: composer error 2]

i installed laravel global installer, but it shows symfony things error, i have reinstalled composer but it doesn't work

Comment: install laravel directly using: `composer create-project laravel/laravel yourapp`

Comment: Did you recently updated from composer v1 to v2 ?

Comment: Composer might complain if the path length is exceeding 250 chars. Your temp directory path is quite long. Maybe its too long.
You could download `composer.phar` into your project directory and try it from there..

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form, the command you were running, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @Jonathan no, i installed from exe file and it's already v2

Comment: @KGG it gives me a new error.

In ZipDownloader.php line 184:

  Failed to extract laravel/laravel: (7) C:\MinGW\bin\7z.EXE x -bb0 -y "D:\RO
  SHIT FOLDER\coding\PEMROGRAMAN WEB\vendor\composer\tmp-8acc2771dbb758d217be
  46b4ad4c0801" -o"D:\ROSHIT FOLDER\coding\PEMROGRAMAN WEB\vendor\composer\79
  2fc40f"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

please see this url ( [installation laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation))

**first: install composer on OS (Linux , Windows or MAC)**

If you have already installed Composer, you must be clear chache in composer:

```
php composer.phar clear-cache
```

or this command:

```
composer clear-cache
```

then Using installation via composer:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think this is a caching issue?

Comment: I did clear-cache before I made this post, and it's not working